# MS Reporting Services not authenticate on local domain name

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I can access my reports through

```
http://mymachine:808/Reports
```

or

```
http://localhost:808/Reports
```

but not

```
http://myhost.mydomain.com:808/Reports
```

even when I have `myhost.mydomain.com` map to `127.0.0.1` in the `host` file. It was keep asking user name and password, but the same user name and password works fine in other ways to access.

How to fix this?

**Update**

It prompts to type in user name and password, but just to pop up again. So there is no way to get into the page with the broken URL.

This is consistent in at least 2 browsers: Firefox 47.0, and Edge 25.10586.0.0

Also, I didn't have Report Manager installed, here is my menu of Reporting services configuration manager:

[image]

Comment: Does it accept them? Is the issue that it is prompting or is the issue that even when you enter them they don't work? If it's just prompting then it's probably just IE settings thinking you're hitting an external website and turning off auto login. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid See my update.

Comment: So it pops up three times, you enter it three times then a web error message comes up? If so please edit and add the error message. It really helps to explain the symptom clearly and completely.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No... I didn't say I entered it three times and then an error message comes up. It is just keep pops up, regardless how many times you enter...

Comment: OK that's the kind of thing we need to know.... because there is a classic login symptom where that happens.... and this clearly isn't it :). Have you tried prefixing your login with the 'domain' (i.e. mymachine\mylogin)

Comment: Another thing to try is to just put an image in a public space in your web server and try accessing that via `myhost.mydomain.com` and seeing if you get prompted. If you do then the issue is with the web server. If you don't then the issue is with Reporting Services

Comment: 1. I tried prefix with the machine name but it is the same. 2. I have local IIS service in myhost.mydomain.com and works perfectly: no prompts, just the website's login page. 3. So the conclusion is the issue is with Reporting Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the hint in comments the issues is in the Reporting Services.

I was using the default settings, but MSDN said you can have different authentication types. I checked my `reportserver.config` file and I was using NTLM. Change it to use basic authentication solves the problem.

My guess of the reason, is that the browser will send a "Host" property for every request, and as this is inconsistent with NTLM's "domain", so Reporting Services reject the authentication. However, when switch to basic authentication, it simply pass the credential to Windows, so now it accepts.

References:

- [Authentication Types in Reporting Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281310(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [How to: Configure Basic Authentication in Reporting Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for returning and posting your solution - you should be able to accept it as correct

Comment: As I was the one that asked the question, I cannot accept my own answer before tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a new URL for Report Manager. To do this

- Open Reporting Services Configuration Manager
- Select Report Manager URL
- Click Advanced
- Click Add to add details

Here's a screenshot to help.

[image]